# What exactly is meant by backwards compatibility in case of Java Generics?

Tags: java, generics

`Generic type information is not available at runtime in Java for backwards compatibility reasons.`

What exactly compatibility reasons mean here? Also is generic type information available in some cases or is it ALWAYS unavailavble and are there any other reasons than backwards compatibility?

I have some knowledge about it but I would like to finally understand it if anyone would be kind enough to answer this question. I have read read several articles and bits of Oracle documentation but they weren't focused on the problem I'm trying to figure out here.

Comment: It's not just backward compatibility. Deciding not to increase the amount of runtime type information means that the inefficiencies of carrying that information around are not realised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Type information is **always** erased. Imagine you have a set of strings, you would (now) use `Set<String>` - but before generics were added it would be simply `Set`. To ensure backwards compatibility when generics were added to Java (in 2004 with J2SE 5.0) the type information is removed. So `Set<String>` compiles to `Set` to allow compatibility with code written before generics were added.

Comment: You mean it right. but, i think you are using wrong terminology saying *Set<String> would still run on Java versions without generics*. Can you make it bit more clear?

Comment: Yeah, what he means is that the generated bytecode is backwards compatible. So for all intents and purposes the bytecode does not know about generics.

Comment: The answer is at best misleading. Class files produced by javac using generics in their source will not run on JVM versions prior to 1.5. However, 1.5+ source code can use pre-1.5 source and class files (although there will typically be warnings). There was the odd program (retroweaver) which enable 1.5+ code to run on pre-1.5 JVMs.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline thanks for clarifying, I was clearly mistaken regarding the backwards compatibility, I've modified the last line so it's hopefully more accurate now.