# How to check if a generic type of class is implementing some interface

Tags: java, generics, casting

I have this class :

```
public class Bird extends AbstractEntity<Long> implements IHasWings {
}
```

And some other classes that extends `AbstractEntity` but they don't implement `IHasWings`, for example :

```
public class Cat extends AbstractEntity<Long>{
}
```

I pass these classes as a type argument in their DAO classe, like this :

```
public class BirdDAO extends AbstractDAO<Bird, Long> { ... }
```

and

```
public class CatDAO extends AbstractDAO<Cat, Long> { ... }
```

So all the DAO classes are extending the `AbstractDAO` class.

In `AbstractDAO` class I have this :

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T extends AbstractEntity<ID>, ID extends Serializable> { 
    public List<T> findAll(){ 
        AbstractEntity entity = ...
        if (entity instanceof IHasWings) {
            IHasWings entityWithWings = (IHasWings) entity;
            //Do something with entityWithWings.getWingSize();
        }else{
            //Do something else
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test if the passed type argument is implementing `IHasWings` as you can see above, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

I tried the following :

```
Class<T> entity = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
    .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
if (entity instanceof IHasWings) {...}
```

Which threw this error : `Incompatible conditional operand types Class<T> and IHasWings`

How can I solve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467362/in-java-why-is-there-no-generic-type-info-at-run-time

Comment: Your `if (entity instanceof IHasWings)` at the bottom is equivalent to `class instanceof class`. A class is, by definition, not an instance of anything.

Answer (score 4):

Your check is incorrect in that it's verifying that an instance of `Class<?>` is an instance of `IHasWings`. The compiler prevents `instanceof` checks using objects and types that have no relationship (`java.lang.Class` objects can never be instances of your `IHasWings` interface).

What you're looking for is a way to find out whether `IHasWings` is compatible with the class object in `entity`. For that, what you need is:

```
IHasWings.class.isAssignableFrom(entity)
```

From the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)) (`java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)`):

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but then how can I cast `entity` so I can do `entity.getWingSize()` ?

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki You mean inside `findAll`? There are two variables named `entity` in your question, one being a `Class`, the other being an `AbstractEntity`. I believe the way you have it in `AbstractDAO` will work, assuming the actual creation of `AbstractEntity entity` instance uses the correct class to create the object. [But why are you using the raw type `AbstractEntity`? Is this a sign of a problem? Or is this because you're using reflection to instantiate objects?]

Comment: Well I wrote `AbstractEntity entity = ...` because I didn't know how to instantiate `entity`, that's not the final code.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki Right. Then I'm sure `if (entity instanceof IHasWings)` will work if the correct `AbstractEntity` subclass is used at runtime.

Comment: Emm, actually I get this compilation error : `Incompatible conditional operand types Class<T> and IHasWin` when I do that.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki That's why I said you have two variables named `entity` in the question. The second one would give that compiler error (and that's the one my answer was about), but the first one (in your `AbstractDAO.findAll` method) wouldn't.